# Sprite not rotating after scaling in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

There is a circle I want to rotate. If it is not scaled its rotates perfect but when it is scaled it is not rotating on its center point. I am using .setsize(--) function to scale and .setrotation(-) function to rotate. Can any one give me the solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you scale the Sprite and before calling setRotation(), be sure and call

```
yourSprite.setRotationCenter(pRotationCenterX, pRotationCenterY)
```

Comment: what will be the values of pRotationCenterX and pRotationCenterX

Comment: half of the getScaledWidth and scaled height.